# What happens to my local project files when I create a new git branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

Suppose I have a repository on my local machine, a working directory where I make changes and push to remotes, and I decide I would like to add a new feature which will in time replace an in place feature.

What happens when I create a new branch and start modifying my working directory? If I switch to the new branch and start making changes, those changes are overwriting code on my local machine, are they not?

So if I have two branches, one Master and one NewFeature, how can I maintain copies of both on my local machine up until I decide merging is ready?

How is this normally done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a folder on the repo with the name `.git`, this folder contains all the information that is necessary for your project in version control and all the information about commits, remote repository address etc. all are present in this folder. It also contains a log which stores your commit history so that you can roll back to history.

When you working on `Master` branch, on your local folder you have the files of the `Master` branch.

When you run the command `git checkout NewFeature` and in this branch have any changes from `Master` branch, you local folder will be overwriting the `Master` with `NewFeature` changes.

**But** you do not lose your `Master` branch content, it saves on `.git` folder, when you will go back to the `Master` your local folder will be changed again.

So - you don't have yo maintain your 2 branches, GIT does it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling this is what would happen, but I wasn't sure. To be clear, when I checkout a branch, the files in my working directory will be changed to reflect the head of whatever branch I'm checking out, right? And also when I switch back?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when I create a new branch and start modifying my working directory?

Git branches are effectively a pointer to a snapshot of your changes.

If you just create a new branch without switching to it by:

```
    git branch <my_branch>
```

you are still on local master branch changing files as left in your working directory by master branch checkout with further changes you made locally and on master branch before this git branch command.

Creating and switching to my_branch (off master branch) by

```
    git checkout -b <my_branch>
```

is equivalent to:

```
    git branch <my_branch>
    git checkout <my_branch>
```

so it will create my_branch out of your master current position and switch to it immediately, which means your working directory files will be in state from master as since now maintained on this new my_branch.

> If I switch to the new branch and start making changes, those changes are overwriting code on my local machine, are they not?

The changes locally overwrite the state of the working directory, of the branch state you have just switched to.
Your master branch state is unchanged and can be restored by git checkout master.

If you are new to git please follow the git tutorial from Atlassian:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches
And basically start building your git skills there from the very beginning.

Since you do not know git internals yet, leave the .git/ directory.
It is your whole git repo implementation with all your files data and git meta-data (incl. all branches) to allow your git work on workspace next to it.
This .git/ directory is created after git init command when you setup new repo
or is cloned by git clone before the checkout process restores the working directory files from it.

> So if I have two branches, one Master and one NewFeature, how can I maintain copies of both on my local machine up until I decide merging is ready?

Git does it for you in .git/ directory repo, checking out only the content of the branch you work currently on into the workspace (working directory of your repo).

Good luck on finishing the git tutorial and understanding the concepts how git actually works. Next step would be to learn on different git workflows https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows and select one to use in your project.